# Creating a Facebook Like button on Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-like

I'm trying to provide a Facebook Like button in my Android app and am having problems. I think that I have everything set up properly:

I'm calling FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

I've added a LikeView into my activity

I've created an app id using the appropriate key hashes

I've added the following into the manifest inside the application tag:

```
   <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
      android:configChanges=
             "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
      android:label="@string/app_name" />

    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider000000000099893"
      android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
      android:exported="true"/>
```

Where 000000000099893 is my application id (I've zeroed out most of it)

My app is crashing in Facebook's Utility.java class on the line:

```
FetchedAppSettings settings = fetchedAppSettings.get(applicationId);
```

Actually it crashes within the HashMap code with a null pointer

This leads me to believe that something is going wrong with my application id. What else should I be looking at?

Comment: I recommend posting the code around fetchedAppSettings, including the initialization.

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after going through all of the code in the SDK and some of the samples I finally figured out what was going on. It seems that I need to add

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"                android:value="@string/app_id"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName"
android:value="@string/facebook_app_name" />
```

into the manifest.

I just downloaded the SDK today - it says that the version is 4.2.0 but the instructions on the Facebook site do not mention these manifest changes.

Disappointed.